# How to find index of an Array element in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, ocaml-batteries

I am trying to find the index of an integer array element in ocaml. How to do this recursively. 
Example code:`let a = [|2; 3; 10|];;`
suppose I want to return the index of 3 in the array a. Any help appreciated. I am new to OCaml programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You check each of the elements recursively using an index

```
let rec find a x n =
if a.(n) = x then n 
else find a x (n+1);;

find a x 0;;
```

that will raise an exception (when n is bigger than the length of the array) in case the element is not part of the array.

Comment: I better understand this answer. May be other answers are better but I still have to learn more to understand them. And I think exception raising could be avoided by checking if n > (Array.length  a -1) then 'some integer value to indicate not found' as first expression in function find.

Answer (score 4):

```
type opt = Some of int | None;;

let find a i =
  let rec find a i n =
    if a.(n)=i then Some n
    else find a i (n+1)
  in
  try 
    find a i 0
   with _ -> None
;;
```

Test

```
# find a 3;;
- : int option = Some 1
# find [||] 3;;
- : int option = None
# find a 12;;
- : int option = None
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let f xs x =
  let i = ref (-1) in
  let () = Array.iteri (fun n elt -> if x = elt then i := n else ()) xs in
  !i
```

The return value will be `-1` if the element is not in the list.